# How do I flag a question which seems more appropriate on android enthusiasts?

Tags: feature-request

While flagging questions,we have an option which says **This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.**

But what about other sites, like *android enthusiasts*.I think atleast we should be able to suggest all tech sites on SE network.

Comment: "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" but make sure it follows the golden rule: **DON'T MIGRATE CRAP**. Is good idea dropping by the target site chatroom and ask the folks if they consider the question as a good one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3749/add-a-migrate-to-xx-se-site-option-in-the-off-topic-section-for-flagging-quest?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4220/add-unix-and-linux-to-the-off-topic-menu?lq=1

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3914/more-destinations-for-off-topic-questions?rq=1

Comment: @FEichinger can you put all those links into one comment? That would be better.

Comment: @adityapatil They're separate for a reason. Each of these comments follows a simple schema of "Related: {Link}", and each of these comments can be handled separately if needed (rather than having to get a moderator to edit it instead).

Comment: A link to the question you're referring to would be helpful! Or is this just a general query?

Answer (score 2):

There will never be a complete list of alternative sites in the close reason. There are just too many (100+) and there is a character limit in the close reason. (I've suggested a [possible alternative](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8418/176889))

Thus, the "not about Ubuntu" flag is usually sufficient.

If you really feel that the question should be migrated, use a "needs ♦ moderator attention" flag, as they're the only people who can handle that anyways.

Comment: I suggested just tech sites.and we can always group them

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases.

- If it would have been better somewhere else but is acceptable here, don't close it at all.
- If it's off-topic here because it's really not about Ubuntu, then use the "not about Ubuntu" sub-reason under off-topic. As [minerz209 says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8464/22949), the correct site (if there is one) doesn't have to be listed in the description of the "not about Ubuntu" reason, for that reason to be used. It's a catch-all for questions that aren't about Ubuntu.

  If you're sure it's not about Ubuntu but think it would be unclear to *others* (the OP or other members of the community such as close reviewers), you can post a comment explaining why you believe it's off-topic and should be closed.

In [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), [Shog9](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/author/josh-heyer/) explains about how one should not close otherwise on-topic questions just because they'd be *better* somewhere else:

> #### Respecting your own community
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that*
> community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to
> push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be
> appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided
> to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers
> away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else.
> Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their
> question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps
> a bit with another site’s, so be it.
>
> Obviously, there are questions you’ll have to turn away, either
> because their *only* connection to your site is via the audience (“How
> do I make bread as a *programmer*?”), because it’s completely
> off-topic (“How do I cook a fish in a dishwasher?” obviously belongs
> on Cooking, not Home Improvement) or because they’re simply not useful
> or constructive. But that should be your last resort. Close questions
> with an eye toward *improvement and re-opening*, not driving users
> away.

(emphasis in original)